# Prevent a Modal form closing all Modeless open forms upon exit

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I ran into some peculiar behavior while using VBA Forms in Excel. I have a module which invokes a Modeless form, which serves as a hub to call other forms. The other forms are invoked as Modal. The problem is, as soon as the the child form is hidden or unloaded, the parent Modeless form gets closed as well.

I tried to find an answer to this, but even though there are questions that exist along these lines, none of them provided an answer that works.

After a bit of testing, I determined any number of open Modeless forms would be closed in the same way. Furthermore, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue using a minimal model in a new Workbook. After that, I went on to add piece-by-piece all the components (there are a few modules, 10-20 classes, and a few forms) of the original Workbook to see when the problem comes up.

I was simultaneously relieved and annoyed when I found that the problem didn't reappear even after I imported absolutely everything back. My conclusion was that this was some kind of a fluke that won't bother me again. But, soon after, when I added another such child form, with identical calling code, the same started happening again with the new one, but not with the old one.

I then proceeded to export the misbehaving form, delete it from the workbook, and then import it. And voila, it worked again.

Is there anyone who encountered such behavior before? Am I doing something wrong? Or should I treat this as an annoying but circumventable bug?

Please find below the minimum model of the problem, excluding all the content:

module calling the main form:

```
Sub testA()

 Dim main1 As MainForm1

 Set main1 = New MainForm1

 main1.Show (vbModeless)

End Sub
```

main form:

```
Option Explicit

Dim formobject As frmPickInjection

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Set formobject = New frmPickInjection


 With formobject
     .Show (vbModal)
     Label1.Caption = CStr(.SelectedInjection)
 End With

End Sub
```

child form:

```
Option Explicit

Public passvar As Boolean

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 passvar = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

System: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 6.1.7601 (Service Pack 1 Build 7601)

Excel version: Office365 Excel 2016 (16.0.6729.1014), 64 bit

VBA version: 7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encountered this problem before.
Unsure whether this has already been resolved or not, but for future users looking to fix this:

The only way I have found of fixing this annoying and intermittent issue is to show the userform Modally then Hide and re-show the userform Modelessly.

```
Unload MyChildUserform
MyParentUserform.Show vbModal
MyParentUserform.Hide
MyParentUserform.Show vbModeless
```

It's clunky and annoying, but it seems to work and is consistent at the least.

**Edit:**

IMHO A much better solution is to control the modality of the form yourself.

Declarations:

```
Public Declare Function EnableWindow lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd as Long, ByVal fEnable as Long) as Long
Public Declare Function FindWindow lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName as String, ByVal lpWindowName as String) as Long

Public Enum MakeAsModal
    Modal = 0
    Modeless = 1
End Enum

Public ghWndParent as Long
```

Public Sub(s):

```
Public Sub ChangeModality(ByRef hWnd as Long, ByVal isModal as MakeAsModal)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim RetVal as Long
    RetVal = EnableWindow(hWnd,isModal)
End Sub
```

Parent Form:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
'Parent Form
    ghWndParent = FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
End Sub

Private Sub CallChild()
'Parent Form
    ChildUserform.Show vbModeless
    ChangeModality ghWndParent, Modal
End Sub
```

Child Form:

```
Private Sub Userform_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode as Integer)
'Child Form
    ChangeModality ghWndParent, Modeless
End Sub
```

Comment: Fascinating! I didn't manage to resolve it, but I was simply ok with the workaround: export all forms - import back all forms, which I assigned to a macro.

Does one need to do this command sequence once, and then it fixes it for the time being, or does this have to be a part of the form's calling code?

And out of curiosity - how did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: I actually had a further play around with it and found a much better solution... although it does involve WinAPI commands. Will correct answer above with new solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was plagued with this issue today, I found a work around that stops the closing of non-modal forms on the close event of a modal form.

Simply, set the UserForm property "`ShowModal`" to `True`

[UserForm ShowModal Property to True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNxgc.png)

Then; when showing the form just use `UserForm.Show` (i.e. *do not specify* `vbModal` or `vbModeless`). In my work-around I contained this `.Show` call inside the `UserForm_Initialize` event of the respective modal UserForm. Now when you close this modal form, it won't take out every parent non-modal form with it.

This issue was vital for me to find a workaround for, since my modal Userform MUST be modal since it contains a RefEdit control. After some further investigation and troubleshooting, I cannot derive exactly what is causing this issue with Modal forms. I'd love someone with better knowledge in VBA to take a look, but I'm afraid they may have all moved on to greener pastures....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a *really* old thread, but I found it looking for answers to this same question so I figured I would share my solution in the hopes that it helps someone else.

Another option I found was not creating the modal form as a new form; rather, if you just show the form as modal instead of initializing a new one, it will hide properly without hiding the parent forms.  Of course, this doesn't work if you need to have multiple instances of this particular form simultaneously, but for my purposes (it brings up a search user form to select a value that it passes back to the parent form), hiding afterwards worked for me.

Comment: Interesting. Haven't used VBA actively in a while - do you mean to say that the form needn't be initialized at all and you just Show the class itself (e.g. from my code frmPickInjection.Show())?. I.e. there is a default instance and as long as you don't need more than one you can use that one as a singleton?

If that really reproducibly works it's a nice workaround, but I'd still prefer Gnixxus's approach, which appears more universal, without being horribly complex either.

Comment: Correct on all counts so long as by class you are referring to the userform and not an actual class.

Comment: My use case was a search box that I reuse to fill multiple different textboxes on different forms.  On the event AfterUpdate on a textbox, I update public variables (SearchText as String, SearchType as String) with the search value/parameters for which search to execute, then show the form as modal.  The form executes a sql command using the public variables and returns a list of records to a listbox.

Comment: I use the value selected in the listbox in another public variable, which the original userform will read and write the results to the TB when I double click the value in the listbox or click the select button, which also hides the search userform.  The search userform will then be hidden without closing the "parent" form (which I guess it's not really a parent form since it's not initializing a new instance of the search form).

Sorry for the multiple posts, didn't realize there was a char limit till after I wrote that whole thing out lol

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I assume it is so, but are the instances between copies of the same workbook separate? I.e. if you copy the workbook under a different name and open it simultaneously and use this approach, the same-named forms won't clash since they are in separate VBA projects and so different forms?

Comment: Ah, I did not consider concurrent copies of the form in different workbooks, never came up in my apps yet...I typically only have the one WB open.  It's possible different WBs themselves are separate instances and it wont conflict.  I actually don't use the worksheet to store any data in this particular app (everything is from the SQL and held in public vars in the forms), so I've only got 1 the WB open at a time, I'm just using VBA for the front end as I don't know other languages/cant get it working with SQL (I know a lot, but I'm not a pro, just creating app(s) for fun/in my spare time lol)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sounds like what I used to do some 5-6 years ago, until VBA became just too limiting and I bit the bullet and went for VB.NET, and later C#. Would wholeheartedly recommend, nowadays even if I want to use it within VBA, I implement it as a library and use the .dll functions from VBA. Cheers!