# Close a built-in modal dialog

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to close a built-in modal dialog via VBA? The issue is that the code stops when a modal dialog appears and can only continue once it's closed. Sendkeys doesn't work. Example of a dialog that needs closing:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FontShadingColorMoreColorsDialog"
```

Comment: Look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401393/prevent-a-modal-form-closing-all-modeless-open-forms-upon-exit/51220139

Comment: @SharifLotfi this doesn't work in this scenario as we are dealing with a built-in modal dialog. We have no control over it's modality as far as I'm aware